# git how to force push to checked out remote branch

Tags: git

i checked out a remote branch like `git checkout -b newBranch origin/some-remote-branch` but whenever i do a push it is pushed to a new branch `newBranch`. How do I tell git to automatically push to the branch I checked out from origin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push origin newBranch:some-remote-branch
```

Or if you want it to do it automatically when you run `git push`, edit the entry in your `.git/config` to read as follows

```
[branch "newBranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/some-remote-branch
```

You can also run `git branch -u origin/some-remote-branch newBranch` instead of editing `.git/config` manually.

And make sure you also have the following setting, so that push will push to the upstream by default (right now, the default is to push to the matching branchname):

```
[push]
    default = upstream
```

You can run `git config push.default upstream` to set this, or `git config --global push.default upstream` if you want to set this option globally for all of your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the branch to push to specific remote branch, you need to set the upstream branch with `git branch -u origin/some-remote-branch`.  Then you will only need to run `git push`

If it is always pushing to `newBranch`, I think that you are doing `git push origin newBranch`.  This command pushes a new remote branch `newBranch` onto origin.